# CSP error occured when on build an extension with Flutter included Firebase Auth

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build an extension with Flutter sources included Firebase Auth.
is occurred a CSP error.

what should I do?
is there any way to solve this problem? or BP examples?

flutter build web (OK)

web extension build ( CSP error)

- Modify manifest.json, index.html for web extension build
  (ref. [Building a Chrome Extension Using Flutter](https://medium.com/flutter-community/building-a-chrome-extension-using-flutter-aeb100a6d6c)

[YouTube - how to add firebase to a service worker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UjH2INUPmF4&ab_channel=RustyZone)

[CSP Violation in GitHub core](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9817)

Answer (score 0):

The CSP errors are because extensions require that the scripts they are running be packaged inside the extension and flutter web uses scripts from a CDN. If you want, you can look through the output generated by flutter and try to replace those references to be locally packaged scripts.

This [solution is also mentioned](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9817#:%7E:text=There%20is%20only%20one%20solution) in the issue you linked.